# Converting text data into Json format

Tags: python, json

I am beginner to Python.

I have to convert the text data into Json Format

Here is the sample text data extracted from the table structure below:

```
Metric - Column 1 ,
Design Project - Column 2 ,
Design Target* - Column 3 ,
Median Property* - Column 4

Metric Design Project Design Target* Median Property*
Source EUI (kBtu/ft²) 3.1 Not Available 127.9
Site EUI (kBtu/ft²) 1.0 Not Available 40.7
Source Energy Use (kBtu) 314.0 Not Available 12,793.0
Site Energy Use (kBtu) 100.0 Not Available 4,074.2
Energy Cost ($) 2,000.00 Not Available 81,484.00
Total GHG Emissions (Metric Tons CO2e) 0.0 Not Available 0.5
ENERGY STAR score (1-100) Not Available 75 50
```

Here is the code below:

```
import csv
import json

with open('output.txt', 'r') as csvfile: # Opens file
    filereader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    i = 0
    header = []
    out_data = []
    for row in filereader:
        row = [elem for elem in row if elem]
        if i == 0:
            i+=2
            row[1:3] = [row[1]+" "+row[2]]  # Design Project key
            row[2:4] = [row[2]+" "+row[3]]  # Design Target key
            row[3:5] = [row[3]+" "+row[4]]  # Median Property*
            header = row
        else:
            row[0:3] = [row[0]+" "+row[1]+" "+row[2]]  # Metric 
            if len(row) == 5:  # check conditions for better parse
                row[1:2] = [row[1]]  # Design Project value
                row[2:4] = [row[2]+" "+row[3]] # Design Target

            _dict = {}
            for elem, header_elem in zip(row, header):
                _dict[header_elem] = elem
            out_data.append(_dict)

    print json.dumps(out_data)
```

Above code which is working for first two lines of the data correctly.

Here is the output of the code,

```
[{"Metric": "Source EUI (kBtu/ft\u00b2)", "Design Target*": "Not Available", "Median Property*": "127.9", "Design Project": "3.1"}, {"Metric": "Site EUI (kBtu/ft\u00b2)", "Design Target*": "Not Available", "Median Property*": "40.7", "Design Project": "1.0"}]
```

How can I make the complete data into a json format?

Comment: Your data is not consistent. And `row = [elem for elem in row if elem]` will have different number of elements for 3rd data row than for 2nd data row. That is why it is not working. You probably need to separate extraction in multiple cases e.g. when `len(row) == 5` do one conversion, and when `len(row) == 6` do other conversion

Comment: But if i write IF ELSe condition its throwing error @PerunSS

Comment: Can you add what you've tried?

Comment: @PerunSS Solved and updated my code , Please have a look and help me in more precise way to code that

Comment: You can optimize code a bit, e.g. by extracting what is common to be executed after all `if`s, but that is it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Answer,

```
import csv
import json

with open('output.txt', 'r') as csvfile: # Opens file
    filereader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    i = 0
    header = []
    out_data = []
    for row in filereader:
        row = [elem for elem in row if elem]
        if i == 0:
            i+=1
            row[1:3] = [row[1]+" "+row[2]]  # Design Project key
            row[2:4] = [row[2]+" "+row[3]]  # Design Target key
            row[3:5] = [row[3]+" "+row[4]]  # Median Property*
            header = row

        elif len(row) == 8:

            row[0:4] = [row[0]+" "+row[1]+" "+row[2]+" "+row[3]]  # Metric value

            if row[1] == 'Not':
                row[1:3] = [row[1]+" "+row[2]]
            else:
                row[1:2] = [row[1]]  # Design Project Value
                row[2:4] = [row[2]+" "+row[3]] # Design Target

            _dict = {}
            for elem, header_elem in zip(row, header):
                _dict[header_elem] = elem
            out_data.append(_dict)

        elif len(row) == 7:
            #print len(row)
            row[0:3]=[row[0]+" "+row[1]+" "+row[2]]  # Metric Value
            row[1:2] = [row[1]]  # Design Project value
            row[2:4] = [row[2]+" "+row[3]] # Design Target

            _dict = {}
            for elem, header_elem in zip(row, header):
                _dict[header_elem] = elem
            out_data.append(_dict)

        else:
            row[0:6] = [row[0]+" "+row[1]+" "+row[2]+" "+row[3]+" "+row[4]+" "+row[5]] # Metric Value
            row[1:2] = [row[1]]  # Design Project value
            row[2:4] = [row[2]+" "+row[3]] # Design Target
            _dict = {}
            for elem, header_elem in zip(row, header):
                _dict[header_elem] = elem
            out_data.append(_dict)

    print json.dumps(out_data)
```